# Parallelization over for loop analyzing a data.frame

Tags: r, parallel-processing, data.table, data-mining

These days I've been working with a data.frame of 8M registers, and I need to improve a loop that analyzes this data.

I will describe each process of the problem that I am trying to solve. 
First, I have to arrange all the data.frame in ascending order by three fields ClientID, Date and Time. (Check)
Then, using that arranged data.frame, I must operate the differences between each of the observations, where it can be only done when the ClientID is the same. For example:

```
ClientID|Date(YMD)|Time(HMS)
A|20120101|110000
A|20120101|111500
A|20120101|120000
B|20120202|010000
B|20120202|012030
```

According to the data up, the result that I want to obtain is the following:

```
ClientID|Date(YMD)|Time(HMS)|Difference(minutes)
A|20120101|110000|0.00
A|20120101|111500|15.00
A|20120101|120000|45.00
B|20120202|010000|0
B|20120202|012030|20.30
```

The problem now is that, analyzing all this with a data.frame of 8M observations, it takes like 3 days. I wish I could parallelize this process. My idea is that the data.frame could be segmented by clusters, but this segmentation could be in order and not randomly, and then using the library foreach or another library, could take by clusters the analysis and set it to the number of cores available. For example:

```
Cluster|ClientID|Date(YMD)|Time(HMS)
CORE 1|
1|A|20120101|110000
1|A|20120101|111500
1|A|20120101|120000
CORE 2|
2|B|20120202|010000
2|B|20120202|012030
```

Comment: A by group time difference calculation should not take 3 days for merely 8m observations. What code are you using now?

Comment: R is *slow*. It uses some amazing fast libraries underneath, but actual R code is one of the slowest languages you will find. To make your code faster, use as little R as possible, and rewrite performance critical code in C, Fortran, etc. like all the good R packages do.

Comment: @Anony-Mousse -- I'm not saying you're 100% wrong, but I strongly disagree with your recommendation _"use as little R as possible, and rewrite performance critical code"_. With efficient R code leveraging  packages like `data.table` you can work with 100 million+ row data-sets without speed being a limiting factor. There's a _very good reason_ high level scripting languages exist and we aren't all writing Fortran routines every time we need to read a CSV and graph something- the ease of use (with a slight trade-off on performance) makes R a great choice for a surprisingly wide range of tasks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't recommend trying to parallelize this. Using the `data.table` package and working with times stored in an integer format this should take a pretty trivial amount of time.

#### Generate some example data

```
library(data.table)

## Generate Data
RowCount <- 8e6
GroupCount <-1e4

DT <- data.table(ClientID = paste0("Client ",sample.int(GroupCount,size = RowCount, replace = TRUE)),
                 Time = sample.int(12,size = RowCount, replace = TRUE)*900)

DT[, Time := cumsum(Time), keyby = .(ClientID)]
DT[, Time := as.POSIXct(Time, tz = "UTC", origin = "1970-01-01 00:00:00")]

print(DT)
```

gives

```
            ClientID                Time
      1:    Client 1 1970-01-01 02:30:00
      2:    Client 1 1970-01-01 04:00:00
      3:    Client 1 1970-01-01 05:30:00
      4:    Client 1 1970-01-01 07:00:00
      5:    Client 1 1970-01-01 10:00:00
     ---                                
7999996: Client 9999 1970-02-20 18:15:00
7999997: Client 9999 1970-02-20 18:30:00
7999998: Client 9999 1970-02-20 21:00:00
7999999: Client 9999 1970-02-20 22:45:00
8000000: Client 9999 1970-02-21 00:30:00
```

### Calculate time differences

```
system.time({
  ## Create a integer column that stores time as the number of seconds midnight on 1970
  DT[,Time_Unix := as.integer(Time)]

  ## Order by ClientID then Time_Unix
  setkey(DT, ClientID, Time_Unix)

  ## Calculate Elapsed Time in minutes between rows, grouped by ClientID
  DT[, Elapsed_Minutes := (Time_Unix - shift(Time_Unix, n = 1L, type = "lag", fill = NA))/60L, keyby = .(ClientID)]

  ## Clean up the integer time
  DT[,Time_Unix := NULL]
})
```

...

```
   user  system elapsed 
  0.416   0.025   0.442
```

#### Results:

```
print(DT)
```

...

```
            ClientID                Time Elapsed_Minutes
      1:    Client 1 1970-01-01 02:30:00              NA
      2:    Client 1 1970-01-01 04:00:00              90
      3:    Client 1 1970-01-01 05:30:00              90
      4:    Client 1 1970-01-01 07:00:00              90
      5:    Client 1 1970-01-01 10:00:00             180
     ---                                                
7999996: Client 9999 1970-02-20 18:15:00             135
7999997: Client 9999 1970-02-20 18:30:00              15
7999998: Client 9999 1970-02-20 21:00:00             150
7999999: Client 9999 1970-02-20 22:45:00             105
8000000: Client 9999 1970-02-21 00:30:00             105
```

Comment: Excellent! It works pretty well. Will be using from now on data.tables :)

Comment: Glad this helped, if you're regularly working with millions of rows you'll never look back! The package has a [Getting Started page](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Getting-started) with some good resources.  I've also found [Advanced tips and tricks with data.table by Andrew Brooks](http://brooksandrew.github.io/simpleblog/articles/advanced-data-table/) has some great examples of some of the less frequently used capabilities.

Comment: Thanks for knowledge!